# “Class Not Found” during SonarQube analyse

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1.2

I have many errors with sonarqube analyse in the Jenkins job with the analyse success

```
[ERROR] [14:36:44.124] Class not found: org.joda.convert.FromString
[ERROR] [14:36:44.126] Class not found: org.joda.convert.ToString
[ERROR] [14:34:42.441] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [14:34:42.724] Class not found: org.apache.oro.text.perl.Perl5Util
[ERROR] [14:34:31.442] Class not found: io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel
[ERROR] [14:34:31.442] Class not found: io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty
[ERROR] [14:28:37.756] Class not found: org.apache.commons.logging.Log
[ERROR] [14:28:40.030] Class not found: org.apache.oro.text.perl.Perl5Util
```

SonareQube : 5.1.2

sonarQube jenkins plugin : 2.6

JDK : 1.7

Any help please

thanks

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. This is my jodatime dependency in the project: `joda-time:joda-time:2.8.1`

Comment: Can you also provide the version of the SonarQube Maven plugin? For example in logs it should display: 23:00:30 [INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) @ sonar-ant-task ---

Comment: Jenkins SonarQube Plugin : 2.2.1 [INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) with Maven 3

Comment: any solution Julien ?!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following dependency to your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That may help in some cases but it is no remedy for the root cause.

Comment: Did not work for me. I will try this in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593240/class-not-found-error-when-running-sonarrunner

Answer (score 2):

This error is displayed when the .class file of the mentioned class is not found. This might results in less accurate and less precise issues raised.

You should check your analysis configuration and more specifically the `sonar.java.libraries` property to be sure you provide the correct dependency to your project.

Comment: I use Maven build and i don't have a problem when i do mvn install

Comment: So how do you run the analysis on jenkins ?

Comment: with Jenkins sonarqube plugin

Comment: No, not less accuracy...the builds actually fail.

Comment: @MarcelStör This is an unrelated problem.

Comment: @benzonico if there's `[ERROR]...` as seen in the OP's post then the build on Jenkins fails no matter what the reason.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause in our case were outdated Sonar plugins. In order to figure out *which one* it is you need to run a Maven debug build i.e. run it with `-X`. The

```
Class not found: org.joda.convert.FromString
Class not found: org.joda.convert.ToString
```

you'll see if the sonar-jmeter-plugin is not up to date for example.

Comment: It definitely does. After upgrading from 4.5.x to 5.1.2 (same as OP) we saw the exact same output as the OP. The builds failed because `org.joda.convert` wasn't found. Upgrading the Sonar plugins fixed that.

Comment: This error log is not related to the build failure you mention.

Comment: Updating to the latest sonar-maven-plugin plugin (2.7.1) does not solve the issue.