# SonarQube Jacoco JUnit : SonarScanner get many unexpected problems

Tags: maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a simple project that need to Run JUnit test and let SonarQube to scan / run the Test of JUnit result with SonarScanner. I put my project at [Github here](https://github.com/daviduck123/sonar-jacoco-JUnit-Maven)

There are some problems:

1. WARN: Class "XXX" is not accessible through the classloader sonar ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593240/class-not-found-error-when-running-sonarrunner))
2. No jacoco-it.exec and jacoco-ut.exec, only run jacoco.exec at SonarScanner
3. Cannot exclude some files when running Test JUnit, because I only want to Run Test in my Service Folder ([Reference](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreFiles))

This is my sonar-project.properties :

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=com.example:Sample
sonar.projectName=Java :: Example :: SonarQube Scanner
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=src/main/resources/**
#sonar.test.inclusions=src/main/java/com/example/service/**, src/test/java/**
#sonar.test.exclusions=src/main/java/com/example/controller/**

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

#Jacoco
sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
sonar.jacoco.reportPath =target/jacoco.exec
sonar.jacoco.reportMissing.force.zero=true
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes/**
#sonar.java.libraries=libs/**
```

When I Run Maven Test until build success, It create some files and folders in folder **Target**.

[image]

After that I run my SonarScanner to Scan my project, but I got those problems.

My question:

1. How can I run my SonarQube Scanner without any WARN ?
2. How to exclude files properly when scanning JUnit result? Because I use the reference settings, and Coverage still scan the files
3. How to create jacoco-it.exec and jacoco-ut.exec and run it on SonarScanner?

My project is based on this [Reference](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project)

Comment: You don't need `sonar-project.properties` if you are using Maven: please refer to documentation about Analysis using Scanner for Maven - http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven usage of it should be enough to avoid many configuration headaches, e.g. such as warning `Class "XXX" is not accessible`. `jacoco-ut.exec` and `jacoco-it.exec` are products of execution of `jacoco-maven-plugin` for unit tests and integration tests respectively.

Comment: I use sonarqube and sonarscanner as third party. That's why I have sonar-project.properties. I download the RAR of SonarQube and SonarScanner, and then First, I start my SonarQube and then I go to CMD, going to my folder (sampleProject) and then I run my Scanner. The setting of my SonarScanner vased on sonar-project.properties

Comment: Q: "How can I run my SonarQube Scanner without any WARN ?" A: Use SonarQube Scanner for Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SonarQube Scanner **for Maven**](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) instead of just [SonarQube Scanner](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner). Otherwise you fall into troubles with configuration, into which you fall, because need to do everything manually:

- `sonar.sources` most likely is incorrect - should be `src/main/java`  and will be properly configured by Scanner for Maven, and that's why you're getting undesired test files analysed as main files
- as well as `sonar.tests` that normally for Maven based projects points to `src/test/java`
- `sonar.java.libraries` is empty and that's why you're getting `Class "XXX" is not accessible through the classloader sonar` - it might be quite hard to list all required JAR files of dependencies of your Maven project, while again Scanner for Maven will do this automatically and most importantly will do this correctly
- `sonar.projectKey` with Scanner for Maven will be set automatically to Maven groupId:artifactId
- `sonar.projectName` and `sonar.version` with Scanner for Maven will be set correctly to Maven project name and version respectively, so that you don't need to change version, when it will change in Maven project
- others such as `sonar.sourceEncoding`, `sonar.java.binaries`, `sonar.java.test.binaries` and `sonar.java.test.libraries` with Scanner for Maven will also be set automatically

If needed you'll still be able to provide other additional properties

- via command line such as `mvn ... sonar:sonar -Dsonar.something=something`
- or in SonarQube UI
- or specify them directly in `properties` section of `pom.xml`

> How to create jacoco-it.exec and jacoco-ut.exec and run it on SonarScanner?

Usually `jacoco-ut.exec` refers to coverage data about unit tests and `jacoco-it.exec` refers to coverage data about integration tests. They are created by `jacoco-maven-plugin`, in your `pom.xml` you configured `jacoco-maven-plugin` for creation of `jacoco.exec`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and those explanation. My bad using SonarScanner.
How can I run coverage unit test only on my specific folder?
For example in my Github project, I only want Jacoco coverage on Service files. So I need to exclude the other files except Service. But when I run mvn sonar:sonar, it still scan all the files in my Project.